# Changing more than one bit in a register

Tags: c, embedded, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have an 8 bit register and I want to change bits 4,5 and 6 without altering the other bits.
Those bit can take values from `000` to `111` (regardless their previous state).
Is there a method to change them in one step or must I change them individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mask to put the requested bits in a **known state**, 0 is the more convenient as per my programming habits, then set the bits that you want to 1 with an or operation and write back:

```
#define mask 0x70    // 01110000b bit 4, 5 & 6 set
reg = (reg & ~mask) | (newVal & mask);
```

We use the inverted mask to set to 0 the bits to change and the unchanged mask to set to 0 the bits that we don't want to interfere from the new value.
If you are sure that the unwanted bits of the new value are always 0 you can simplify:

```
#define mask 0x8f    // 10001111b bit 4, 5 & 6 reset
reg = (reg & mask) | newVal;    //newVal must have always bits 7, 3, 2, 1 & 0 reset.
```

Comment: I don't see how `0` is more convenient than `1` for the known state.  It's just a question of whether in the next step you turn on the bits you want on (with an `|` operation), or turn off the bits you want off (with an `&` operation).

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I consider more convenient the 0 because to set the wanted bits, as you said, you just need an `or` between values, to reset them you need to `and` the register value with **the inverted** input value. You need 2 operations.

Comment: No, the alternative can be exactly as complex as your example, and it does not require inverting the input: `reg = (reg | mask) & (newVal | ~mask)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes it can be an alternative. I'll add that this is my personal preference to clarify that I prefer this, but the reverse is possible.

Comment: Your second example is incorrect - it won't ever clear any of bits 4, 5, or 6 if they are currently set in `reg`.  I think that you should just remove that second part from your answer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks!. I forget to remove the `~` from the mask. I think that if the setting of bits comes from a clean source the second part could be useful if speed and space have to be saved.

Comment: You have imposed pre-conditions on `newVal` in the second example that you explicitly ensured by applying the mask in the first - why not use those pre-conditions in the first or mask it in the second per @JohnBollinger's suggestion?

Comment: Possibly worth noting that the read-modify-write pattern is not thread safe.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for comment. The second suggestion is in case the `newVal` is already clean to remove an instruction in speed/space sensitive cases. Of course it is not thread safe, the implementation depends on CPU/System where it runs.

Comment: @Frankie_C : Ah, my apologies; I see that now, I misread your comment starting *" I'll add that..."* as meaning that you were going to add that suggestion, rather than that your merely adding a point in justification.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by bitwise operation, i.e. first clear the 3 bits, and then set them:

```
unsigned char value = 0x70;
unsigned char r = 0xFF;
r = (r & 0x8F) | value;
```

Comment: I think you mean bitwise or `|` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bit-field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) inside a struct:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned char b0_3 : 4;
    unsigned char b4_6 : 3;
    unsigned char b7   : 1;
}your_reg_type;

your_reg_type my_register;

//modify only the bits you need
my_register.b4_6 = 0x02;
```

Check out how your compiler orders the bits inside the struct before trying and [order your bit-field accordingly](http://mjfrazer.org/mjfrazer/bitfields/)

Comment: this answer is not (necessarily) correct, as there is no guarantee in C, that the first bit listed is bit 7.   It can be bit 0.

Comment: That's why I said "check out the endianess of the target..."

Comment: For a single byte, it is not a matter of endianness, but rather compiler implementation.  In fact even for multi-bytes it is still not a matter of endianness- endianness is about byte order not bit order.  The compiler may pack bits from MSB or LSB regardless of byte order.  So check your compiler's documentation rather then the target endianness.  Be aware that this could change between different compilers for the same target.

Comment: Often vendor supplied compiler specific  target processor header files are provided that do exactly this for on-chip peripheral registers.  Which if fine if the vendor  chooses to supply a header for the specific tool-chain you are using, but may hamper portability to alternative compilers..

Comment: You're right, it's a matter of compiler implementation. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A number of solutions and variations are possible (and have been suggested already), but if the value of the three consecutive bits has meaning in-itself (i.e. it is a value 0 to 7 rather then simply a collection of independent flag  or control bits for example), it may be useful to keep the value as a simple numeric range 0 to 7 rather then directly encoding details of bit position within the value.  In which case:

```
     assert( val <= 7 ) ;  // During debug (when NDEBUG not defined) the
                           // assert trap will catch out-of-range inputs

     reg = (reg & mask) | (val << 4) ;
```

Of course there is some small cost to pay for simplifying the interface in this way (by adding a shift operation), but the advantage is that knowledge of the details of the register field layout is restricted to one place.